# Media Queries - does it matter if in css file or html?

Tags: media-queries

I want to use media queries to alter my design for phones and other mobile devices.

It seems I can either have the following within my css file:

```
@media handheld and (max-width: 480px),  
screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
}
```

Or, I can have something similar as part of the link to the CSS file, in my page html. Is their a difference between these two methods or is the result the same? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same.  Check the "Meet the media query" section of this link for even more choices on how to introduce them: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/